# How do you change a variable in a function to then be used in the main code?

Tags: python, function, variables

I am quite new to Python and I am having some trouble figuring out the following:

```
import random
import sys

print("Welcome to this Maths quiz.")
playerName = str(input("Please enter your name: "))
playerAge = int(input("Please enter your age: "))
if playerAge < 11:
    print("This quiz is not for your age.")
    sys.exit(0)
else :
    print("Great! Let's begin.\n")

quizQuestions = ["9(3+8)", "7+9*8", "(9+13)(9-5)", "50*25%", "104-4+5*20"]
quizAnswers = ["99", "79", "88", "12.5", "0"]
quizSync = list(zip(quizQuestions, quizAnswers))
random.shuffle(quizSync)
quizQuestions, quizAnswers = zip( * quizSync)
questionNumber = 1
quizScore = 0

def displayQuestion(quizQuestions, quizAnswers, questionNumber, quizScore):
    print("Question " + str(questionNumber) + ": " + quizQuestions[questionNumber - 1] + "\n")
    questionAnswer = str(input())
    if questionAnswer == quizAnswers[questionNumber - 1]:
        print("\nCorrect!\n")
        quizScore += 1
    else :
        print("\nIncorrect! The answer is: " + quizAnswers[questionNumber - 1] + "\n")

while questionNumber < 6:
    displayQuestion(quizQuestions, quizAnswers, questionNumber, quizScore)
    questionNumber += 1

print("You have a total score of: "+str(quizScore))
```

I would like the variable "quizScore" in the function "displayQuestion" to increase by one if the player gets a question right. However, after the quiz is finished, the print function at the end always prints the score is 0 even if the player gets questions right.

Comment: Do you get "Correct!" printed?

Comment: Yes, I get "Correct!" and "Incorrect" printed with the respective answer.

Comment: For one, `displayQuestion` doesn't return a string, so why are you printing it in `print(displayQuestion(quizQuestions, quizAnswers, questionNumber, quizScore))`?

Comment: global the quizScore in your function .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this won't be the shortest answer, which is to use another global variable. It instead will show you how to avoid using global variables ([which are considered harmful](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesConsideredHarmful)) by using [Object Oriented Programming (OOP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). To accomplish this, most of the code in your question can be encapsulated into a single class named `MathQuiz` below.

Besides getting rid of almost all global variables, it also provides a usable template for you to create any number of independent math quizzes.

```
import random
import sys

class MathQuiz:
    def __init__(self, questions, answers):
        quizSync = list(zip(questions, answers))
        random.shuffle(quizSync)
        self.quizQuestions, self.quizAnswers = zip(*quizSync)
        self.quizScore = 0

        print("Welcome to this Maths quiz.")
        self.playerName = str(input("Please enter your name: "))
        self.playerAge = int(input("Please enter your age: "))
        if self.playerAge > 10:
            print("Great! Let's begin.\n")
        else :
            print("This quiz is not for your age.")
            sys.exit(0)

    def run(self):
        for questionNumber in range(len(self.quizQuestions)):
            self._displayQuestion(questionNumber)

        print("You have a total score of: " + str(self.quizScore))

    def _displayQuestion(self, questionNumber):
        print("Question " + str(questionNumber) + ": "
              + self.quizQuestions[questionNumber-1]
              + "\n")
        questionAnswer = str(input())
        if questionAnswer == self.quizAnswers[questionNumber-1]:
            print("\nCorrect!\n")
            self.quizScore += 1
        else :
            print("\nIncorrect! The answer is: "
                  + self.quizAnswers[questionNumber-1]
                  + "\n")

quiz = MathQuiz(["9(3+8)", "7+9*8", "(9+13)(9-5)", "50*25%", "104-4+5*20"],
                ["99", "79", "88", "12.5", "0"])
quiz.run()
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare it as a global variable inside the function so that it can modify the variable in the global scope

```
def displayQuestion(quizQuestions, quizAnswers, questionNumber):
    global quizScore    
    ...
    quizScore += 1
```

That being said, you should generally avoid global variables if you can and try to redesign your program to either pass the variables along as arguments and return values, or use a class to encapsulate the data.

Comment: Do you mean something along the lines of this:
http://pastebin.com/Dd0BiFag

Comment: You can't both pass `quizScore` in as an argument and use it as a global variable.  Either you pass it in as an argument and then return it as a return variable, or you make it a global variable and modify it in place